# Integrating jQuery Image Crop into Wordpress for avatar image upload

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, image

I am trying to use [this plugin](http://demo.w3bees.com/jquery-image-crop/) with my wordpress site, but have had little success.

I can select the image, and use the square select tool to make a selection. The problem arises when I try to add this cropped selection to my already existing form where I upload my avatar image. When I click submit, I am directed to a "404 page not found" page.

Obviously I have included all the accompanying scripts and have checked with Firebug that they have loaded correctly.

Here is what I have done:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["registration_form_submit"])) {

    $counting_faults = 0;

    if ($counting_faults == 0) {

    $account_settings_displayname = preg_replace("/\s+/", " ", $_POST["account_displayname"]);
    $account_settings_displayname = str_replace("@", "", $account_settings_displayname);

    /* Enter the values into WordPress DB */
    $generate_user = wp_update_user(
                    array(
                                    'ID' => $current_user_data->data->ID,
                                    'display_name' => $account_settings_displayname,
                                    'user_email' => preg_replace("/\s+/", " ", $_POST["account_email"]),
                                    'first_name' => preg_replace("/\s+/", " ", $_POST["account_fullname"]),
                                    'description' => mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST["account_bio"]))
                    )
                    );

    $outcome = @array_shift(array_values($generate_user->errors));
    }

    /**
    * ******** Avatar image upload starts here *********
    */
    if (isset($_FILES["file_name"]["name"]) && $_FILES["file_name"]["name"] != "") {

    $user_id = $current_user->ID;

    /* Create the uploads folder if it doesn't exist */
    $directory_name = "wp-content/uploads/" . date("Y") . "/";
    if (! is_dir($directory_name)) {
            mkdir($directory_name, 0755);
    }

    $directory_name = "wp-content/uploads/" . date("Y") . "/" . date("m") . "/";
    if (! is_dir($directory_name)) {
            mkdir($directory_name, 0755);
    }
    $filename = $directory_name . basename($_FILES["file_name"]["tmp_name"]) . "-" . $_FILES["file_name"]["name"];

    echo $filename;

    $uploaded_file = move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file_name"]["tmp_name"], $filename);


    /* The part I need your help with -- Stars here */

    $valid_exts = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif');
    $max_file_size = 200 * 1024; #200kb
   $nw = $nh = 200; # image with # height

    $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['file_name']['tmp_name']));
    echo 'ext'.$ext;
    if (in_array($ext, $valid_exts)) {
            $path = 'uploads/' . uniqid() . '.' . $ext;
            $filename = $filename;
            $size = getimagesize($_FILES['file_name']['tmp_name']);

            $x = (int) $_POST['x'];
            $y = (int) $_POST['y'];
            $w = (int) $_POST['w'] ? $_POST['w'] : $size[0];
            $h = (int) $_POST['h'] ? $_POST['h'] : $size[1];

            $data = file_get_contents($_FILES['file_name']['tmp_name']);
            $vImg = imagecreatefromstring($data);
            $dstImg = imagecreatetruecolor($nw, $nh);
            imagecopyresampled($dstImg, $vImg, 0, 0, $x, $y, $nw, $nh, $w, $h);
            imagejpeg($dstImg, $filename);
            imagedestroy($dstImg);
            echo "<img src='$filename' />";

    }

    /* The part I need your help with -- ends here */

    /* Upload the image to WP structure */
    $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype(basename($filename), null);

    $wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

    $attachment = array(
                    'guid' => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename($filename),
                    'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
                    'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($filename)),
                    'post_content' => '',
                    'post_status' => 'inherit'
    );

    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $filename);
    require_once ('wp-admin/includes/image.php');
    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $filename);
    wp_update_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $attach_data);
    delete_user_meta($user_id, 'wp_user_avatar');
    add_post_meta($attach_id, '_wp_attachment_wp_user_avatar', $user_id, true);
    add_user_meta($user_id, 'wp_user_avatar', $attach_id, true);
    }

    /**
    * ******** Avatar image upload ends here *********
    */
    ?>


    <form method="post" action="" name="account" id="account"   enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <div class="settings-box">


    <li><label class="primary-label">Profile Image</label>
    <div class="formFields"><?php  echo get_avatar( $current_user->user_email, 100 ); ?><br />

            <div>
            <!-- image preview area-->

            <img id="uploadPreview" style="display:none;"/>

            <!-- image uploading form -->

                    <!-- hidden inputs -->
                    <input type="hidden" id="x" name="x" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="y" name="y" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="w" name="w" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="h" name="h" />
                    <input id="uploadImage" type="file" accept="image/jpeg" name="file_name" />
            </div><!--wrap-->

            </div></li>

    <!--    <input type="file" name="photo" id="photo" /><br /><br /> -->

    <li><div class="form-footer s-in">
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <input class="btn" type="submit"
                            name="registration_form_submit" value="Update" />
            </div></li>

    </div>

    </form>
```

Comment: What's the name of the plugin you referenced in the link?

Answer (score 0):

In this line, is your action="" actually/intentionally blank? Your form may be trying to call a non-existent page:

```
<form method="post" action="" name="account" id="account"   enctype="multipart/form-data">
```